# Remove a file in previous commit/changeset

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, kiln

A few revisions ago I committed a piece of work in which I accidentally included a 300mb .flv file (don't ask...).

Is there a way I can edit that changeset to not include the aforementioned file?

UPDATE:
I think I can use the MQ extension and follow [these instructions](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EditingHistory) (chapter 6). However, when I run: `hg qimport -r 11:tip`, I receive the error: `abort: out of memory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`hg convert`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--filemap) with `--filemap` switch. Do note that IDs will change on modified changesets and their children. If you've already pushed it to a remote location, you need to use strip/convert on that repo as well, before pushing again.

Comment: When I tried to push to Kiln it would abort without a reason. I presume it was due to the size! Thanks for the answer, I am trying your suggestion now.